# Variable property name in html:text tag

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts, struts-1

I'm using struts-1 and want to use a concatinated string as a property name in a html:text tag. The string is composed of a static String and a parameter given from a jsp:include tag.

**The include part**

```
    <jsp:include page="test.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="language" value="DE" />
    </jsp:include>
```

**The html:text**

```
    Param: ${param.language}
    <html:text property="propertyDE" name="bean" />
```

**The not working html:text code**

```
    Param: ${param.language}
    <html:text property="<%="property" + param.language%>" name="bean" />
```

Is there a way to use a dynamic value in the property attribute in html:text? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use :

```
<c:set var="language" value="DE" />
```

importing `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

and then use the variable as `${language}`

Comment: there is also `<c:out value="language"/>` depending on your preferences

Comment: Thanks. A solution is to concat the string as follows <c:set var="concat" value="property${param.language}" /> and use it as follows in the html:text: <html:text property="${concat}" name="bean" />

Comment: did you just triy to had `${param.language}` without the `<c:set />`

Comment: This was not the problem. I had problems with concatenating the static String "property" and the ${param.language}

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to use it as follows:

```
<html:text property="property${param.language}" name="bean" />
```

Comment: Yes, that whas my last comment. Actually, you could also create this variable on your server, then use one the scope you put it in, request, session etc... It would be easier to maintain.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my intentions. I wanted to make like a jsf composite component in struts-1. So I used the jsp:include with a jsp:param. The included jsp looks always the same. The only difference is the language Postfix in the getter and setter method